# How do I change the text of a Mockup Button

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I use the Button from the Mockup Buttons collection, is there any way to change the text on the button so it doesn't say "Button Text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpOotAMvn0c) for changing the text in the ER shapes, the same idea applies for the mockups ("mainText" is the style key). We are working on a custom properties dialog for changing this, obviously this method is wrong.

Comment: Bwhahaha, that is the most user-unfriendly way to change those properties! Thanks for the tip! And good job on having all the properties already abstracted and just needing a dialog. As an alternative UI idea, maybe you could set up each style key be an item on the format menu?

Also, can I put in a feature request for an e-mail text box? (I'm mocking up a mailing list signup form, and we just want to collect the user's email address and have a button).

Thanks David!

Comment: Email text box coming up in next release.

Comment: Party on! You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue earlier, I figured out how to change the actual text on the pre build diagrams.

Go to >>>**file**>>> and  select >>>>**Edit**<<<, a  window  appears and allocate the names of the buttons in this case the names are button 1, button 2, button 3.  change to the diresed text name. if you wish to add new button place a comma after the end of the last button and write the name of the new button..